# Detect Region Format on Mobile Safari (IOS) with PHP (<5.3 ) or JAVASCRIPT

Tags: php, javascript, user-agent, regional-settings

I'm going Mad trying to get the **user Region Format** (not the language) from a IOS/mobile Safari browser;

I want to redirect a user to a US page if for example he had these settings:
Language : EN
Regional : US

but **i always get en-us** on mobile safari,
either if the system settings are both language = en, region= en

I tried both Server side and Client side apporach

with PHP I tried (system settings: lang=en / region=en)

```
$lang_string = $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'];
echo $lang_string;
//en-US,en; on Chrome Desktop
//en-US; on Safari Desktop with UserAgent iPad
//en-US; on Mobile Safari
```

with javascript approach, (system settings: lang=en / region=en)

```
alert(window.navigator.language)
```

always **en-us**!!

is there a way to get the user region?

(i know that should be possiible with [The Locale class (PHP 5 >= 5.3.0, PECL intl >= 1.0.0)](http://php.net/manual/en/class.locale.php) I but did not tested and I can't upgrade the server version)

thank you for help!